# Path to profile picture in Moodle?

Tags: php, database, moodle

I was programming something in moodle web-application and was looking into retrieving the path of the user profile images.

I assumed I could find the path somewhere in the database but I only got to mdl_user.picture and mdl_user.imagealt, so practically I know who has uploaded a picture but can't get to which picture he/she uploaded.

Is there a way to get it from the database?

Thanks for your help,

OM

Comment: I've created a proposal for a Stack Exchange website for Moodle users and developers. This question would be a perfect fit for it, rather than for Stack Overflow. http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/33861/virtual-learning-environments

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want the image tag you can use print_user_picture() and pass the user object that you got from the database. You can also specify the size of the image. So to print the full size user picture for the current user you could do

```
global $USER, $COURSE;

print_user_picture($USER, $COURSE->id, null, true);
```

Otherwise if you need just the url you have do do something like this

```
require_once($CFG->libdir.'/filelib.php');

$size = array('large' => 'f1', 'small' => 'f2');

$src = false;
if ($user->picture) {
   $src = get_file_url($user->id.'/'.$size['large'].'.jpg', null, 'user');
}
```

Comment: I have added a folder under moodledata like PDFdata  how to access it..  I tried this method it says "Invalid Course Id".. Please help

Answer (score 5):

in moodle 2.0 you can use this

```
global $USER,$PAGE; 
$user_picture=new user_picture($USER);
$src=$user_picture->get_url($PAGE);
```

Answer (score 3):

this one works for me in 3.4 version

```
<?php echo new moodle_url('/user/pix.php/'.$USER->id.'/f1.jpg')?>
```

Answer (score 1):

The OP requested getting this information from the database, other posters gave hints on how to get it from moodle using PHP - but if you don't have access to moodle code, this is the way to do it..

you need to first find the instance ID for the user's id (3) in example.

Then you need to search the files table for a hash of the instance ID /user/icon/f/f[1-3].[jpg|png]

this query will give all files, in size order, where the largest file is first.

the first column file_path will be the file path relative to the moodle files on your server.  see config.php for `$CFG->dataroot` for its location.

```
select @instanceID := id instance_id
from mdl_context where contextlevel = 30 and instanceid = 3; # instanceid = 3 is user id 3
select @instanceID; # check it is present.
;
SELECT concat(left(f.contenthash,2),"/",substring(f.contenthash,3,2),"/",f.contenthash) file_path, f.pathnamehash, timecreated, filename, f.*
FROM mdl_files f
LEFT JOIN mdl_files_reference r ON f.referencefileid = r.id
WHERE f.pathnamehash in(
    sha1(concat("/",@instanceID,"/user/icon/0/f1.jpg")),
    sha1(concat("/",@instanceID,"/user/icon/0/f2.jpg")),
    sha1(concat("/",@instanceID,"/user/icon/0/f3.jpg")), 
    sha1(concat("/",@instanceID,"/user/icon/0/f1.png")),
    sha1(concat("/",@instanceID,"/user/icon/0/f2.png")),
    sha1(concat("/",@instanceID,"/user/icon/0/f3.png")))
order by timecreated desc, filename desc
```

Answer (score -1):

To get the User profile pic simply you can use the following path:

NOTE: used userid = 3 and appended with number 2

Path : http://moodleservername/moodle/pluginfile.php/23/user/icon/clean/f1

Comment: this is incorrect, 23 is the context id, not user id = 3 appended with the number 2.