# Display users profile picture to visitors moodle 2.8

Tags: moodle

I am using moodle2.8
I have to display users profile pictures on visitor panel(no user logged in).
I got the user_id.

I seen the link [Path to profile picture in Moodle?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840187/path-to-profile-picture-in-moodle)

```
require_once($CFG->libdir.'/filelib.php');

$size = array('large' => 'f1', 'small' => 'f2');

$src = false;
if ($user->picture) {
   $src = get_file_url($user->id.'/'.$size['large'].'.jpg', null, 'user');
}
```

But puttting this says no file found.

Is there a way to get user profile image source, using user_id?

Thank you for help.

Comment: please go through below mentioned URL: [https://stackoverflow.com/a/53207384/8825817](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53207384/8825817)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this

```
$user = $DB->get_record('user', array('id' => $userid));
$userpicture = $OUTPUT->user_picture($user);
$userurl = new moodle_url('/user/view.php', array('id' => $user->id));
$userlink = html_writer::link($userurl, $userpicture .' '. fullname($user));
echo $userlink;
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to use uppercase in this variable: `$USER`

```
if ($USER->picture) {  
    $src = get_file_url($USER->id.'/f1.jpg', null, 'user'); 
    echo $src;
}
```